# How to reset mysql to factory settings?

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb, homebrew

So I dropped all the users in mysql.user and restarted the mysql database. Now I can't seem to get into the mysql again or how to reset it as if it was a clean install. I tried uninstalling it with `brew uninstall mariadb` and then reinstalling it with `brew install mariadb`, but that didn't fix it. The only resources I can find is about how to restore a user from inside mysql (which I am struggling to get into) or how to delete mysql completely by deleting files in certain directories (which don't exist in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods:
method 1:
1.Uninstall the mysql database, delete the data files in the /data directory, and then reinstall

Method 2:
1.Stop the mysql service (systemctl stop mysqld)
2.Delete the files in the /data directory (rm -fr /data/*)
3.Initialize mysql (mysqld --defaults-file=/mysql/my.cnf --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/mysql/app/mysql --datadir=/mysql/data/3306/data/)

PS1: The path may be different from yours, you need to change it according to your own data directory

Comment: This is a MySQL only answer, but the ambiguity of the original question hints significantly towards MariaDB.

Comment: I installed mariadb, but I still get all the mysql commands in my terminal.

Comment: Explicitly `mysqld` doesn't' support `--initialize`, `mariadb-install-db` is used.

Comment: In Windows, find it with _C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data_.
In the case of not running the latest version of MySQL Server, modifying _MySQLInstaller - Community_ in Windows Settings => Installed Apps and upgrading the MySQL Server entry is the quickest.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up finding a solution to my problem. I didn't end up getting it from one source, but more cobbled a bunch of different stuff together until I figured out that this worked.

1. Stop the server: `brew services stop mysql`
2. Start it with this command: `mysql --skip-grant-tables`
3. Run this command to fix the table with no users: `mysql_upgrade --force`
4. Force kill mysql: `ps -ef | grep mysql` followed by `kill -9 <pid>`
5. Start up the server again: `brew services start mariadb`

I did first try `mysql_install_db` instead of `mysql_upgrade --force` as some site suggested, but that didn't work since `mysql.user` table still existed. It was just empty.